# Data structure for changing form using Django Models and Admin app

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a Django application and using the built-in ORM. I would like to create functionality to provide a form but the template for that form needs to be built on admin side of the application and can change over time. 
For instance, initially they have a form that asks for first name, last name but later if they decide to add birthday field admin should be able to go to this template page add birthrate as new field and on client side, users start seeing it. Is there anything already in place that can be used? I was thinking of using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402217/how-to-store-a-dictionary-on-a-django-model) but decided to check here and see if there is something better available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712688/creation-of-dynamic-model-fields-in-django) what your are looking for?
I have never heard about any library for that, because you have pretty much different approaches to handle that!, but check the link, he is explaining better those approaches.