# How to add item to a object of a queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I make a searchqueryset with haystack in django and I have a query set:

```
results = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(q)
```

What I need is to add an item to each object of that query set.
What I have is something like this:

```
results[0].object.name
results[0].object.age
```

etc.
When I get this queryset in my views I want to add an item to each value maybe something like"x_number" and assign it. So when I retrieve de values of each item I have:

```
results[0].object.name
results[0].object.age
results[0].object.x_number
```

(Obviously x_number may have a value to... thats what I need to do actually)

Answer (score 0):

In a SearchQuerySet, .object is just a reference to a model.

If you want to add a field, you can define it on your model, then assign it as you please. If you want to dynamically add a field to a model, that has been discussed here [Creation of dynamic model fields in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712688/creation-of-dynamic-model-fields-in-django).