# How to add field to Page through admin?

Tags: python, mezzanine

I want to be able to add custom fields to Page in my mezzanine app using admin interface. The only solution, that I came across by now is using [django-custard](http://django-custard.readthedocs.org/). However, can this be done using only mezzanine functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creation of dynamic model fields in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712688/creation-of-dynamic-model-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Mezzanine's documentation has an entire section devoted to the topic:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html

Comment: Nope, I mean adding custom field to model on the fly through admin interface, without making changes to model.py

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood you. There's nothing like that in Mezzanine by default.