# How to add a column in table from frontend in django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to add columns to my Django app from frontend. For this, I have created a separate table for table fields but I don't know how can I add a field so that it automatically becomes a field in Contact table and how can i make a dynamic form to ask to fill such inputs.
Thanks in advance.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)


class Field(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_required = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: what do you mean by add columns ?? A record or new field add?

Comment: i want to add a new field in contact table

Comment: you have to add in class and then run commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Then newly add fields will be added!

Comment: I know well, but I want to do it from frontend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712688/creation-of-dynamic-model-fields-in-django

Comment: this link is not for your exact solution but can help you a lot

Comment: maybe use mongoDB for such dynamic task? in accordance with mongoengine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django dynamic model fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields)

Comment: @ArunJain this related question might help you

Comment: Problem solved by creating a separate table. Thanks to guide.