# Create dynamic model field in Django?

Tags: django, dynamic, model

In my models.py my model store contains name, brand_name fields

Now,I want to create new field called brand_type in store model dynamically from Django admin,how can I do this?
Can we change schema of model using SchemaEditor? How?

Comment: why do you need dinamycly creating fields in model?

Comment: I want to create dynamic form where user can add new field with field name, type etc.

Comment: Also I want to change model at runtime

Comment: I think the best you can get is JSON field and store key-value pairs there. Other then that I don't think this is good idea. How would you query or even do any logic when you don't know what field are on each model + field in model code can be different then fields in database?

Comment: Can we change schema of model using SchemaEditor? How?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak can we achieve this by using any other framework other than django

Comment: I'm only aware of using JSONField for this purpose. I'm wondering how do you want to keep your custom field and column in db in sync. Maybe there is simpler solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can't create model's fields via admin panel

you `must` create fields in `models.py`

admin panel is only a convinient way to manipulate your database, but not modifiyng its tables

Comment: So we can’t make model field dynamically ?

Comment: yes, after you make any change in your model you must manually `make migrations`, and `migrate`

Answer (score 0):

It requires migration while the server is running. Create `brand_type` field under your model and set blank=True

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py`

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    name =  ...
    brand_name = ...
    brand_type = models.CharField(max_length = 40, blank= True, null =true)
```

In your console

```sh
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

---

Extra Stuff:

If you are interested in [Text Choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

or

If you wanna make it more **dynamic** based on your use case,
create a model called BrandType and link it in `Store` using

`brand_type = models.ForeignKey(BrandType,on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

`models.py`

```py
class BrandType(models.Model):
    name = ...
    some_other fields=

#... Store model follows
```

`admin.py`

```py
# other stuff
from .models import BrandType
admin.site.register(BrandType)
```

Take away: It is not advisable to modify your `models.py` file using admin directly it will cause integrity issues and there are better ways to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: How can I change model at runtime?

Comment: make changes to the file `models.py` and do `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: What is your feature you want exactly?

Comment: please elaborate _models field dynamically_ and your specific use case.  So we can suggest another way, changing model at runtime is not a good way. You can use database relationships to acheiver your feature ig

Comment: I want to create dynamic form where user can add new field with field name.

Comment: where in admin or in views?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713490/14637144 this one is simpler

Comment: At both admin and views

Comment: Can we change schema of model using SchemaEditor? How?